# How to prevent MS Test from automatically closing application after test is finished?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 Premium. And faced with problem trying to create UI test using [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.aspx)

The problem is application I'm trying to write test for is automatically closed after any particular test is finished. But I need application stay opened after test is finished. Could you please advise how can I get desired result?

Please see code sample:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestsForApplication
{
    private Application application;
    private Commands commands;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        application = new Application();
        if (!Application.IsAppRunning)
        {
            application.OpenApplication(@"c:\Untitled.exe");
        }

        commands = new Commands();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsViewWindowOpened()
    {
        commands.ViewWindow();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        Assert.IsTrue(application.IsWindowAvailable<ViewWindow>());
    }


`application.OpenApplication()` method is implemented based on `Process.Start()` method.
```

So, could you please advise how can I make application not to be automatically closed after test was finished?

Comment: What are you trying to test here? And, are you in control over the application you are testing?

Comment: I'm trying to test if desired form of application functionality is opened. But it's just an example of test. I assume it's not important what I'm going to test. My problem is application I'm trying to test is automatically closed after each test. 

And yes, I'm in control over application I'm trying to test.

Comment: Then I think you should another tool the mstest since each test created its own application scope. I think it is kind of important what you want to test, since that matters when you choose the tools! If you want to test that you "can" (but I would not recommend it, since mstest are for unit tests) merge your test together. To me it looks like you are testing the behavior of .NET applications... or have you written the open/code yourself? You should focus on your own internal logic.

Comment: @Jocke, thank you very much for your advises and comments. I will think about your suggestions. As for my particular problem - installing ReSharper solved the problem.